# Get MVC View Intellisense warning on string param to general method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Visual Studio's Intellisense knows about what View Files are available.

If I write this (typo intentional):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View("Craete", new KeywordViewModel());
    }
```

Then it will whinge, and not underline it and say "can't resolve View".
This is lovely.

If I want to add a layer of indirection, and pass "Create" in via another function:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return ArbitraryIndirection("Craete");
    }

    public ActionResult ArbitraryIndirection(string viewName)
    {
        return View(viewName, new KeywordViewModel());
    }
```

Then I lose this behaviour. Intellisense doesn't *know* that `ArbitraryIndirection` is expecting a View target, so it doesn't check.
This isn't at all *surprising*, but it is *sad*.

Can I teach Intellisense to be cleverer?

Is there something that tells Intellisence that that param is special (I would guess an XML comment reference, or an attribute, maybe?) or is it magic hard-coded into Intellisence somewhere?

Can I get the write-time error-checking on the indirect View reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done this in about a year, but at that time, it was ReSharper which was cleverly verifying the views for me.

If you are using ReSharper, you can make use of the `[AspMvcView]` attribute in the `JetBrains.Annotations` assembly - which you can include via Nuget. A relevant guides appears on the jetbrains website at this link:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/12/07/providing-intellisense-navigation-and-more-for-custom-helpers-in-aspnet-mvc/

Example usage of the `[AspMvcAction]` and `[AspMvcController]` attributes follows (note you'll need the `[AspMvcView]` attribute instead, but I don't have code to hand using that)

```
    public static MvcHtmlString WidgetWrapperAction(this HtmlHelper<dynamic> html, [AspMvcAction] string action, [AspMvcController] string controller, object parameters)
    {
        var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(parameters) { { "area", "AreaName" } };
        var htmlString = html.Action(action, controller, routeValueDictionary);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(htmlString.ToHtmlString()))
        {
            htmlString = html.Action("WidgetLoadFailed", "WidgetLoadFailed", new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", "AreaName" } });
        }
        return htmlString;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks perfect. Thanks!